# How to access item in a nested list of dictionaries python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have the following format saved to a variable:

```
[[{'start': 88608, 'end': 94176}], [{'start': 56352, 'end': 63456}, {'start': 119328, 'end': 151008}], [{'start': 88608, 'end': 114144}, {'start': 123936, 'end': 131040}, {'start': 136224, 'end': 160000}], [{'start': 79392, 'end': 144864}], [{'start': 110112, 'end': 147936}]]
```

How would I go about getting the values attached to start and end labels? For example, how would I get 88608, 56352, 119328 into their own list?

Comment: what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: I would like the end result to be a list of all the start times and a list of all the end times. So far I can get both start and end times using dict.items() but I don't know how to access just start times. I tried val[0] as start is the first item but that did not work either.

Comment: List comprehension example: `[d['start'] for dl in mylist for d in dl]`

Comment: Thanks, I really need to get comfortable with list comprehension this is much simpler than how I was going about it.

Comment: For learning, I recommend [Writing Your First List Comprehension](https://realpython.com/lessons/writing-your-first-list-comprehension/) and their [other videos on list comprehension](https://www.google.com/search?q=realpython+list+comprehension).

Comment: If the list is flattened (either into an explicit list ahead of time, or implicitly as part of a comprehension, or by using a generator) then we simply get the appropriate key from each dict in the flattened iterable - which is what a comprehension is for. Please see the linked duplicates in order to understand the fundamental techniques.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension to iterate over the contents of your list of list of dict. For example:

```
my_list= [[{'start': 88608, 'end': 94176}], [{'start': 56352, 'end': 63456}, {'start': 119328, 'end': 151008}], [{'start': 88608, 'end': 114144}, {'start': 123936, 'end': 131040}, {'start': 136224, 'end': 160000}], [{'start': 79392, 'end': 144864}], [{'start': 110112, 'end': 147936}]]

start_list = [d['start'] for dl in my_list for d in dl]
end_list = [d['end'] for dl in my_list for d in dl]
```

Results are:

```
start_list = [88608, 56352, 119328, 88608, 123936, 136224, 79392, 110112]
end_list = [94176, 63456, 151008, 114144, 131040, 160000, 144864, 147936]
```